# software/solution for direct booting machine will 'wake on lan' another computer and log in virtual PC

Tags: virtual-pc

I have two computers (Window OS) in two different location but in same network. One is very old. I hope the user of that old computer can be very easy to access newer computer.

Ideally, the user turn on the old computer. Then the old computer will send wake on lans message to new computer. The old computer will automatically open the virtual PC in new computer. It will be best if the whole step is automatic. Or it is ok if there can be a shortcut or bat file that can perform all above step.

When the user shut down computer, both computer will be shut down if new computer is not logged in by a window user. Or else, only old computer will be shut down.

I guess that is not such solution? Anyway, I am curious to know.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the steps:

1. Start remote computer using Wake-on-Lan (tools available)
2. Start VM on remote computer (tools available, too, but might need a bit of manual scripting)
3. Log in to VM on remote computer (easy)
4. Shut down VM on remote computer (done by user)
5. On remote computer, shut down if no VM running (can be achieved by a simple script).

Step 2 is probably requiring the most manual work, but in general, this shouldn't be all too difficult.